# Page only displays correctly when cache cleared

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a floating list menu which only displays correctly in firefox directly after clearing the cache, either via menu or with Ctrl + F5. As soon as I refresh the page, the menu is broken again.

The links inside the list elements are wider than the text, but I don't set any width. When I right click on those links the width seems to update to the correct value.

Any ideas?

You can use this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cc43r3nm/2/
Notice the extra space after each main item in firefox, which goes away when you right click on it and move the mouse.

For some reason the Stackoverflow snipped thingy doesn't render it correctly.

```
.navigation {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 800;
}
.navcontainer {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.first_row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul.category_nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  list-style: none outside;
}
ul.category_nav ul li {
  background-image: none;
}
ul.category_nav ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 190px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-top: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* WebKit */
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* Firefox */
  box-shadow: 0 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* Standard */
}
.no-boxshadow ul.category_nav ul {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
ul.category_nav ul a {
  text-transform: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: normal;
}
ul.category_nav ul a:first-letter {
  text-transform: none;
}
ul.category_nav ul ul {
  top: auto;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.category_nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #999;
}
ul.category_nav li:hover ul ul,
ul.category_nav li:hover ul ul ul,
ul.category_nav li:hover ul ul ul ul,
.no-touch ul.category_nav li.hover ul ul,
.no-touch ul.category_nav li.hover ul ul ul,
.no-touch ul.category_nav li.hover ul ul ul ul {
  display: none;
}
ul.category_nav li:hover ul,
ul.category_nav li li:hover ul,
ul.category_nav li li li:hover ul,
ul.category_nav li li li li:hover ul,
.no-touch ul.category_nav li.hover ul,
.no-touch ul.category_nav li li.hover ul,
.no-touch ul.category_nav li li li.hover ul,
.no-touch ul.category_nav li li li li.hover ul {
  display: block;
}
ul.category_nav li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 15px;
  background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/QVCbAqk.png') no-repeat 0 13px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
ul.category_nav li.first_navcontainer {
  padding-left: 0;
  background-image: none;
}
.category_nav li a:first-letter {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.category_nav li li a:first-letter {
  font-size: inherit;
}
.category_nav li li {
  float: none;
}
.category_nav a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="navcontainer" class="first_row">
        <ul class="category_nav">
            <li class="first_navcontainer">
                <a href="">Example 1</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Example 2</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Longer Example 3</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Example 4</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Longer Example 5</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navcontainer" class="second_row">
        <ul class="category_nav">
            <li class="first_navcontainer">
                <a href="">Example 6</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Example 7</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Example 8</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Longer Example 9</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="">Example 10</a>
                <ul class=""><li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make it possible to reproduce your problem before asking. A common solution is to build a [snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't make the problem very clear, because it has an awful lot of extra styles and markup, that don't really do anything.

But boiling the code down to a bare minimum required to show the problem, it's this:

If the first letter of a floating element has a different font size, the browser calculates its width as if the whole element had that size. (Unless the element is an `a` and it has focus, e.g. by right clicking on it.)

```css
span {
    float:left;
}
span::first-letter {
    font-size:1.5em
}
```

```html
<span>This text has a larger first letter</span> This is the rest of the text
```

This sounds like a bug in Firefox. Now I'm terrible with Bugzilla, so I can't find it, but I would be surprised if nobody found it before.

So there's no solution (except to wait until the bug has been fixed), but as a workaround, remove the `::first-letter` styles from your CSS. That's all I have to offer you.

Comment: Thank you! I was completly in the dark, that's why I posted the entire style.